# iPhone Infinite Vertical Text Scrolling

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, infinite, credits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a UIScrollView of infinite scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845789/how-to-create-a-uiscrollview-of-infinite-scrolling)

I'm trying to get a `UIScrollView` to infinitely scroll vertically and wrap around its contents, in this case a *multiline* `UILabel`. (For displaying credits)

I thought it would be a simple case of resetting the offset when at the bottom to the top again to give the illusion that it's scrolling forever.

I tried doing this by using `setContentOffset` of a `UIScrollView` inside `scrollViewDidScroll`, but the problem is that the velocity of the scroll comes to a dead stop when I set the content offset which kills the seamless effect.

Any idea what I'm missing, or if there's a better way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: I used that before and it's the same story. I'd also like to replace the UILabel with a UIView later. Either way they're both UIScrollViews.

Comment: There is a GREAT video from WWDC 2011 on infinite scrolling. I think it was called Advanced ScrollView Techniques. You should be able to get to it through developer.apple.com.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, thanks. It seems I'm already doing what they describe, except when I call setContentOffset the velocity of my scroll does not continue, it just haults. In their developer video the velocity continues so their seamless effect works. I can't find their sample project either :(

Comment: Actually I think I found it, called "StreetScroller". The code is different from the video however, and actually it suffers the same problem that I have - if you do a big swipe, as soon as setContentOffset is called even the sample goes crazy :(